# Dexguard: avoid string obfuscation

Tags: android, dexguard

We are using dexguard and also have the following settings in dexguard-project.txt

```
-keepresourcefiles res/**
-keepresourcexmlattributenames res/**
-keepresources res/**
```

I have also tried variation of providing the 
       res/values/strings.xml like:

```
-keepresourcefiles res/*/strings.xml
-keepresourcexmlattributenames res/*/strings.xml
-keepresources res/*/strings.xml
```

and

```
-keepresourcefiles res/values/*
-keepresourcexmlattributenames res/values/*
-keepresources res/values/*
```

etc

in path.
But strings key-value is getting obfuscated.

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier(key, STRING_FOLDER,context.getPackageName());
```

is returning 0.(where key is a string value).

I have also tried

```
 -dontshrink
```

What is the right way to avoid obfsucation of strings?

Answer (score 4):

In order to keep string resources from being obfuscated / inlined / shrunk by DexGuard, you will need to add the following rule:

```
-keepresources string/**
```

The `-keepresources` directive has the following format:

```
-keepresources [resourceType]/[resourceKey]
```